# How to regenerate views after master page has changed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I have added an another ContentPlaceHolder to Master Page for scripts. When I create Views new place holder is visible, but old views remain the same. Is there a way other than editing all the views by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. Older views need to be update manually if you want to add this new section.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to edit the existing views anyway to add the new content.

If the existing views don't need any content in the new ContentPlaceHolder, then you can leave them untouched and nothing will be rendered for that ContentPlaceHolder when the view is displayed.